# How can I easily correct slight rotational misalignment in scanned images

Tags: images, processing, scanning, rotate

I've got a whole lot of scanned images (> 500) the majority of which were scanned with the paper not completely square. They need to be rotated about 1-5 degrees to be aligned again.

Is there any software that does this? I know some scanner drivers do but mine doesn't seem to.

Update: It seems that thing I want here might be [Image Registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) software.

Comment: Fascinating question. Upvoted. I look forward to seeing what the accepted reply is. (I have no clue myself.)

Comment: Possible solution: http://www.hacktrix.com/fix-alignment-issues-in-scanned-documents

Comment: You are looking for "deskewing". Related questions with some answers: [#204230](http://superuser.com/q/204230), [#444901](http://superuser.com/q/444901).

Answer (score 2):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can handle batch processing, including rotation. Of course you'll need to know which image needs what amount (1-5 degrees) of rotation. You could either rotate all by 1 degree and then review for a further one degree, or check all at the start and put in folders of rotation amount.

> -rotate degrees{<}{>} Apply Paeth image rotation (using shear
>   operations) to the image.
>
> Use > to rotate the image only if its
>   width exceeds the height. < rotates
>   the image only if its width is less
>   than the height. For example, if you
>   specify -rotate "-90>" and the image
>   size is 480x640, the image is not
>   rotated. However, if the image is
>   640x480, it is rotated by -90 degrees.
>   If you use > or <, enclose it in
>   quotation marks to prevent it from
>   being misinterpreted as a file
>   redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package deskew in python.

1. Install the packege

```
pip install deskew
```

2. Use it

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
import deskew


image = skimage.io.imread('input.jpg')
grayscale = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)
angle = deskew.determine_skew(grayscale)
rotated = skimage.transform.rotate(image, angle, resize=True) * 255
skimage.io.imsave('output.jpg', rotated.astype(np.uint8))
```

https://github.com/sbrunner/deskew

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick now has a `deskew` command that can automatically detect how much to rotate. It can also optionally trim off the bits that rotate outside of a rectangular bounding box.

This example command is a good place to start:

```sh
convert input.png \
    -background black \
    -deskew 60% \
    -background black \
    -define trim:percent-background=0% \
    -fuzz 1% \
    -trim-rotate 180 \
    +repage \
    output.png
```