# Which free software can I use to deskew scanned images

Tags: windows, images, batch

I've scanned about 100 documents, so I have a folder with 100 jpg images, but they are rotated by the angle up to 15 degrees. Is there any free simple to use software I can use to rotate them to the normal orientation? It would be good if it works on Windows XP or Windows 7.

Comment: There are some additional potentially helpful answers here: [How can I deskew and crop PDFs made from scanned pages *automatically*?](http://superuser.com/q/444901/11574).

Comment: Sadly most of the software that can do this are made for smartphones. Like office lens, camscanner, notebloc, etc. I only know of ScanTailor on Windows OS and various image editing tools or python scripts (ocrmypdf)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has a -deskew option which may be helpful and the app works very well from the command line on batches of files.

There's some handy Imagemagick scripts [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) - have a look at **unrotate**.

Comment: Thank you. It decreases the angle of rotation of the image from 5-15 degrees (in my original images) to under 2 degrees (but doesn't eliminate it completely).

Answer (score 10):

The definitive tool is [ScanTailor](http://scantailor.org/).
It works like magic for fixing scanned pages and it has a Qt-based GUI frontend.

It allows for batch processing, manual verification and fix of every intermediate step (separation between pages, deskewing, content area identification, noise reduction and optimization) and it's available on every platform (Mac -- via MacPorts or Homebrew, Linux, Windows).

It takes as inputs JPG or TIFF files.

Comment: Its CLI is unmaintained since 2011.

Comment: [Repo](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor) is archived and project is no longer maintained

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to see [unpaper](https://github.com/Flameeyes/unpaper) too.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any image manipulation package will allow you to rotate images. [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net) for example.

Actual deskewing where the image is distorted rather than just rotated is harder and is available in fewer packages.

Answer (score 0):

[ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#example-ocr-and-correct-document-skew-crooked-scan) can deskew PDF pages automatically:

```
ocrmypdf --deskew --clean --rotate-pages input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: It didn't do a very good job on a pdf I tried, text lines are not horizontally straight.